# Excessive use of useTranslation() hook

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I'm using next-i18next to translate my Next.js pages. I'm wondering if using
`const { t } = useTranslation('common')` everywhere for each react component would have a negative impact on performance. The alternative would be calling it in the parent and passing it down to the children which IMO is not a smart solution since it add an extra prop to each component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way to do it.

The alternative as you describe it, passing the function itself as a prop, is essentially the same thing. It would just point to a reference of the original function.

But, passing it as a prop would likely add more overhead to react internally as the rendering process would need to find out if that prop changed, on every component it passes through.

Using `t()` as destructured from a hook, you would just call a reference to the function, nothing more.